# Mypy error Item "None" of "Optional[Dict[str, str]]" has no attribute "get"

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, mypy

The below code runs fine -

```
from typing import List, Dict, Any
def func1(input_list: List[Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]],):
    for config_dict in input_list:
        table_1 = ".".join(
            (
                config_dict.get("src").get("db"), # line 6
                config_dict.get("src").get("schema"), # line 7
                config_dict.get("src").get("table_name"), # line 8
            )
        )
        print(table_1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func1(
        [
            {
                "src": {
                    "db": "db",
                    "schema": "abc",
                    "table_name": "bcd",
                },
                "trgt": {
                    "db": "dd",
                    "schema": "asd",
                    "table_name": "fds",

                },
            }
        ]
    )
```

But when I run mypy on it, I get the following error

```
> mypy abc.py
abc.py:6: error: Item "None" of "Optional[Dict[str, str]]" has no attribute "get"  [union-attr]
abc.py:7: error: Item "None" of "Optional[Dict[str, str]]" has no attribute "get"  [union-attr]
abc.py:8: error: Item "None" of "Optional[Dict[str, str]]" has no attribute "get"  [union-attr]
```

Am I missing something? I want to keep the input_list structure same.

```
mypy --version
mypy 0.991 (compiled: yes)
```

Comment: `config_dict.get("source")` could return `None`; `mypy` is telling you that you can't just assume it is another `dict` whose `get` method you can invoke. (`mypy` performs *static* type checking; it doesn't know or care if you "know" that `config_dict.get("source")` always returns a `dict`.)

Comment: @chepner It was my typo, changed it to `config_dict.get("src")` , is there a way to write type hinting in this case?

Comment: Why are you using `get`? If you're sure the `'src'` key will exist, you should just index the dict. If you're *not* sure the `src` key will exist, then you should handle the key-not-present case properly - just using `get` isn't handling it properly if you proceed to ignore the `None` return case.

Comment: The typo doesn't really matter. *Statically*, `mypy` doesn't know what the *value* of `config_db` will be at runtime, only its *type*.

Comment: This is a *feature*: `mypy` doesn't let you make assumptions about what value of type `Optional[Dict[str,str]]` that `dict.get` might return. The static type includes the value `None`, and your code needs to address the possibility of that occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function annotation is too broad: it permits lists of dicts whose keys don't match the expectations of the function. Instead of `Dict[str, str]`, use `typing.TypeDict` to be more specific. You'll still need to check that `config_dict.get("src")` returns a `TableConfig`, not `None`, but you can assume that a `TableConfig` value *does* have the three keys you try to use. (As in my other answer, I'll switch to `config_dict["src"]` to let the lookup fail via exception rather than a special return value.)

```
from typing import List, Dict, Any, TypedDict

class TableConfig(TypedDict):
    db: str
    schema: str
    table_name: str


def func1(input_list: List[Dict[str, TableConfig]],):
    for config_dict in input_list:
        table_1 = ".".join(
            (
                config_dict["src"]["db"],
                config_dict["src"]["schema"],
                config_dict["src"]["table_name"],
            )
        )
        print(table_1)
```

You might even be more specific, if `"src"` and `"target"` aren't arbitrary keys, but part of your schema.

```
class Mover(TypedDict):
    src: TableConfig
    target: TableConfig


def func1(input_list: List[Mover],):
    for config_dict in input_list:
        table_1 = ".".join(
            (
                config_dict["src"]["db"],
                config_dict["src"]["schema"],
                config_dict["src"]["table_name"],
            )
        )
        print(table_1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `dict.get` has type `Optional[Dict[str, str]]`. That means it *could* return `None` at runtime, so you can't unconditionally assume that the return value has a `get` method. That's the error `mypy` is catching for you.

You can fix this by *checking* first that the return value is a `dict`.

```
def func1(input_list: List[Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]],):
    for config_dict in input_list:
        s = config_dict.get("src")
        if s is None:
            continue

        table_1 = ".".join(
            (
                s.get("db"), # line 6
                s.get("schema"), # line 7
                s.get("table_name"), # line 8
            )
        )
        print(table_1)
```

This is a case where `mypy` can perform type-narrowing. It assumes that if execution proceeds after the `s is None`, then `s` is *not* `None`, and therefore it's type can be "narrowed" (changed to a more specific subtype) from `Optional[Dict[str,str]]` to `Dict[str, str]`.

You can also stop using `get` and use `__getitem__` instead. Here, a key-lookup failure is indicated by an exception, rather than a particular return value, so type narrowing is *also* performed. (Following code will only be reached when the exception is not raised.)

```
def func1(input_list: List[Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]],):
    for config_dict in input_list:
        s = config_db["src"]
        table_1 = ".".join(
            (
                s.get("db"), # line 6
                s.get("schema"), # line 7
                s.get("table_name"), # line 8
            )
        )
        print(table_1)
```

Comment: I tried this, but now I'm getting 
`error: Argument 1 to "join" of "str" has incompatible type "Tuple[Optional[str], Optional[str], Optional[str]]"; expected "Iterable[str]"  [arg-type]` with `if s is None`

Comment: Same issue: `s.get(...)` might return `None`, but you are *assuming* it will return a `str`.

Comment: Yeah, since I'm making sure that the input will not miss any key, I guess it is safe to use `config_dict["src"]["db"]`

Comment: See my other answer for enforcing that assumption at the call site, rather than inside the function.

Comment: I see you used dict1[][] which anyway works with `List[Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]]`